# How to import local git repository into new TFS 2017 project

Tags: git, tfs

I'm using TFS 2017 Express (Team Foundation Server) and am trying to do what I hope is something simple.

1. Create new project in TFS. (done)
2. Import a local git repository containing a project I've been working on for over a year. (not done)

My project is written in Visual Studio 2017. When creating the project, I allowed it to create a local git repository. I committed my changes to local, but hadn't connected to TFS yet. I figured it wouldn't be that big of a deal. It's turning out to be not-simple.

TFS wants me to "clone to Visual Studio", which means that I'd have to migrate everything into that new solution. In my experience, moving projects to another solution in Visual Studio is not as simple as moving documents into a new folder. All kinds of things break and it takes me over half an hour to find all the references that need to be changed.

This is where I am so far. (See screenshots.)

Is there a way that I can *directly* import my local git repository into TFS?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing is probably to create a new (empty) repo in TFS, get the clone URL for it, and configure your local repo to use that URL with

```
git remote add origin <url-from-TFS>
```

(I'm assuming here that you don't already have a remote configured with the name `origin`, and that going forward you want to use TFS as though you had cloned the local from it with default behavior.  If your circumstances are different, you could name the remote whatever you want in place of `origin`.)

After that you can push your local content to TFS.

If you want TFS to be able to import a repo, that repo has to be *somewhere* that TFS can find it with a URL.  That doesn't have to be github; for example it could be a local web server.  In principle I would think it could be a local path or a `file://` URL, but that depends on how TFS views its local environment.

Comment: While I can "add origin" without problem, pushing my local git repository is failing with a whole bunch of errors. I think I'll throw in the towel: clone to desktop and migrate my project to that new solution. What a pain.

Comment: @RandomHandle What are the specific errors? Pushing changes is a fundamental Git function that should be easily accomplished.

Comment: @DanielMann -- "git-credential-winstore.exe" no such file or directory, then updates were rejected because the remote contains work you do not have locally. Trying a pull doesn't help. Maybe I have configuration problems.

Comment: @RandomHandle - The first error ("git-credential-winstore.exe...") sounds like (an old version of) the integration with windows password management may be partially set up.  I don't know off hand how to trouble-shoot that one, but you probably want to address it first as a separate issue, because I expect it to give you trouble with all attempts to access TFS.

Comment: @RandomHandle - "...remote contains work you do not have locally..." should not occur if you created an empty repo on TFS.  Would want to know more about that before recommending a solution.  It might be easiest to resolve the other issue first (to reduce unknowns), but also what output do you get when you do a pull or fetch?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger -- Your answer is correct and I finally got it to work. After using `git remote -v` to see my existing definitions, I needed to use something else other than `origin`. After `remote add` with a different word, I was then able to push to an empty repository. Whew!